# Python Discord Bot problems(eror start)

Tags: python, discord, bots

Full code:[here](https://ideone.com/nCI3TH)

I wrote a bot to display the statistics of the game server in Discord. At startup I have a problem. I use python 3.9.

Problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot1\docker\image\main.py", line 11, in <module>
  BOT_TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']     
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TOKEN'
```

Comment: is your `token` in a .env file?

Comment: No,Token in the bot.py file

Comment: If it’s in the bot.py then why are you using os.environ. That’s for environment variables which are stores in a .env file